# Reactjs - I want to use some json-server mocked data to test my login app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, authentication, json-server

when I use this fetch function and test it on my form, an new object with just an id is created and I get 201 status instead of 200

```
export function PostData(userData){
let url = 'http://localhost:3001/users';

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url,{
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(userData)
    })
    .then((response)=> response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        resolve(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
    });
});
}
```

db.json

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "password": "12345"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "email": "testtest@gmail.com",
      "password": "123456"
    },
    {
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

and this the login function

```
login(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      PostData(this.state).then((result) => {
        let responseJSON = result;
        console.log(responseJSON);
      });
    }
```

the on change function

```
  onChange = async (e) =>{
      this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value} );
      console.log(this.state);
    }
```

Comment: Don't stringify your data - that's done automatically, so is happening twice.

Comment: @Archer thank you for your reply, still the same output!

Answer (score 1):

Status 201 is CREATED - it indicates a successful POST request. Status 200 is the success code for a GET request

Comment: I think my code should console the object matched with my inputs but it doesn't

Comment: You want a fake-backend to intercept the requests and process how you want - check out this section of this blog - its really good - http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example#fake-backend-js